# Redirect based on radio/select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being new to javascript, I'm way in over my head. But I'm trying :P

Basically what I need to do is redirect to a url based on the options selected in the form below. There will be 4 checks in total.

- If Windows & Advanced are selected, redirect to A
- If Windows and Basic are selected, redirect to B
- If Mac and Basic are selected, redirect to C
- If Linux and Basic are selected, redirect to D

However, I'm not quite sure how I would be able to grab the specific names of each radio button and select option, let alone see if they are checked, and make the checks listed above.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
     <form action="process_form.php" class="TTWForm" method="post" novalidate="">
        <div id="field3-container" class="field f_100">
          <label for="field3">Your Operating System</label>
          <select name="field3" id="field3" required="required">
            <option id="field3-1" value="Windows"> Windows </option>
            <option id="field3-2" value="Mac"> Mac </option>
            <option id="field3-3" value="Linux"> Linux </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="field2-container" class="field f_100 checkbox-group required">
          <label for="field2-1">Version</label>
          <div class="option clearfix">
            <input type="radio" name="field2[]" id="field2-1" value="Basic">
            <span class="option-title"> Basic </span> <br>
          </div>
          <div class="option clearfix" id="optional">
            <input type="radio" name="field2[]" id="field2-2" value="Advanced">
            <span class="option-title"> Advanced </span> <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: What if Mac and Advanced are selected or Linux and Advanced?  You have more than four options.  Unless you are hiding the advance radio when Mac or Linux is selected.

Comment: Are you wanting to submit this form with ajax? otherwise the redirect is useless for JavaScript/jQuery. You would be sending over data to the server, which would handle the Form Values. At this point, we'd send a value like `'$_POST['redirecto']` which looks like `http://www.mypage.com/somewhere/something.php`. We would use this to do `header("Location: ".$_POST['redirecto']);`

Comment: @John Hartsock There is no advanced option for Mac/Linux. They're hidden.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy What I'm doing is redirecting to a download based on the options selected in the form.

Comment: @user1368667... You obviously have some additional code to show. Please let us see what you have tried.  It can assist us in helping you.  In additon if you are hiding the fields it would help to see how you are doing this.

Comment: @John Hartsock The rest of my code isn't really relevant to what I'm trying to do. But unfortunately, I'm a noob with javascript, so I really haven't gotten anywhere with this so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a button, and do something on the submit of the form :

```
$(".TTWForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var field2 = $("#field2-1").is(':checked') ? 'Basic' : $("#field2-2").is(':checked') ? 'Advanced' : null,
        field3 = $("#field3").val();

    if (!field2) {
        alert('Select a version!');
        return;
    }

    var url = 'http://mysite.com/' + field2 + '/' + field3 + '/';
    document.location.href = url;
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jnat5/1/)

Comment: There is a button already. I was just trying to keep things fairly compact.

Just tested your code and it's working. I'll try to get all of the options working right.

Thanks for the help. If I get it all working, I'll accept this answer :)